# Pulling specific key:value pairs from JSON url with javascript and CasperJS

Tags: javascript, json, casperjs

Say the url is: https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos

And I just wanted to extract all key:value pairs for the "html_url" key.

I have been trying to use the following:

```
function extractJSON() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data.html_url);
        return data.html_url;
    };

  });

 // casperjs begins below

casper.start(https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos, function() {
});

casper.then(function() {
var output = this.evaluate(extractJSON());
this.echo(output);
});

casper.run();
```

Thank you for your time with this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution could be to scrape the whole text of this site and parse it in json, then you can access the json easy like that:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos';
var text;
var json;

casper.start(url);

casper.then(function() {
  text = casper.fetchText('body pre');
  json = JSON.parse(text);
});
casper.then(function() {
  for (var i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
    casper.echo("html_url: " + json[i].html_url);
    casper.echo("html_url owner: " + json[i].owner.html_url);
  }
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that one! Super appreciated :)